# Error: unable to locate asset entry in pubspec.yaml: "fonts/Ranga-Regular.ttf"

Tags: flutter, dart

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRIPk.png)

I have tried to work but font is not working
Spaces are correct in a file pubspec.yaml
I don't know where the error is and why
There is always an error that makes the font not work
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ZAr2.png)

in file pubspec.yaml

```
fonts:
- family: Ranga
  fonts:
    - asset: asset/fonts/Ranga-Regular.ttf
    - asset: asset/fonts/Ranga-Bold.ttf
      weight: 700
- family: Arimo
  fonts:
    - asset: asset/fonts/Arimo-Regular.ttf
    - asset: asset/fonts/Arimo-Italic.ttf
      style: italic
    - asset: asset/fonts/Arimo-Bold.ttf
      weight: 700
```

in file home_screecn.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

```
 class homescreen extends StatelessWidget {
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
// TODO: implement build
return Center(
    child: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        color: Colors.cyan,
        child: Text("Hi amal",
            textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
            style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black, fontSize: 70, fontFamily: "Ranga" 
                )
                )
                ));}}
```

in main.dart

```
  import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
   import 'layout/home_screen.dart';

  void main() => runApp(MyApp());

   class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
     // This widget is the root of your application.
     @override
     Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return homescreen();




      }}
```

Everything works except fonts
font is not run in emulator

font section
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIt1F.png)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, as stated in the [asking guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) please do not post images of code, instead include in the question the code with the proper formatting.

Comment: Your font files are in the `asset\fonts` folder, NOT 'asset/fonts' folder. So, no matter how much you've tried, you will always get the error if you do not add the `asset\fonts` inside your `pubspec.yaml'

Answer (score 1):

Because you put your fonts file in `asset\fonts` folder, to get it you should add code in your `pubspec.yaml` file based on your folder name.

So your code should be like:

```
  fonts:
    - family: Ranga
      fonts:
        - asset: asset\fonts/Ranga-Regular.ttf
        - asset: asset\fonts/Ranga-Bold.ttf
          weight: 700
    - family: Arimo
      fonts:
        - asset: asset\fonts/Arimo-Regular.ttf
        - asset: asset\fonts/Arimo-Italic.ttf
          style: italic
        - asset: asset\fonts/Arimo-Bold.ttf
          weight: 700
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't add new font into **pubspec.yaml** file so in order to, you should

> import the font files into the project. It’s common practice to put font files in a fonts or assets folder at the root of a Flutter project.For example, to import the Raleway and Roboto Mono font files into a project, the folder structure might look like this:

```
awesome_app/
  fonts/
    Raleway-Regular.ttf
    Raleway-Italic.ttf
    RobotoMono-Regular.ttf
    RobotoMono-Bold.ttf
```

and then go to **pubspec.yaml** file and edit your font section according it's [official site](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/fonts) :

flutter:

```
  fonts:
    - family: Raleway
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/Raleway-Regular.ttf
        - asset: fonts/Raleway-Italic.ttf
          style: italic
    - family: RobotoMono
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/RobotoMono-Regular.ttf
        - asset: fonts/RobotoMono-Bold.ttf
          weight: 700
```

after saving, you should use like this:

```
Text(
  'Roboto Mono sample',
  style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'RobotoMono'),
);
```

Look, i added a font into my **assets/fonts** :

[image]

And i added like this in **pubspec.yaml file**

[image]

Comment: Actually I did this but it doesn't work ,I downloaded the fonts and then I did a folder called asset with a file called Fonts inside it and inside it I put the downloaded fonts and added them inside . look my image description

Comment: please send your font section in ` pubspec.yaml` ? @anaa

Comment: Actually I did, but the font doesn't work . i add screenshot for font section in my post

Comment: It is possible to send project  to me?or create same project and send to me? @anaa

Comment: Yes, of course, how can I send it to you?  Can you give me your email?

Comment: ali.tazik@gmail.com @anaa

Comment: Change your asset forlder to **assets** and also change yaml font section like `assets/fonts/Ranga-Regular.ttf`  https://pasteboard.co/Jgc1pfm.png 
 @anaa